# Comparing code implementations, GCC, if/else->continue

Tags: c, if-statement, gcc

I am working on horrible code.

```
while (x)
{
    if (check1)
    {
        if (check2)
        {
            if (check3)
            {
                function();
            }
            else
            {
                error3();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            error2();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        error1();
    }
}
```

I'd like it to look like this

```
while (x)
{
    if (!check1)
    {
        error1();
        continue;
    }
    if (!check2)
    {
        error2();
        continue;
    }
    if (!check3)
    {
        error3();
        continue;
    }
    function();
}
```

But... This is 'time tested code' that is in many products.....
... and horrible to work with, and will encourage errors in the future.

I need a way to prove that when I change the code to my implementation, the resulting code is equivalent.

Right now when I compile the two versions of code I get different binary files.

Questions:

Is there a way to encourage the compiler to get the same output for both implementations so that I can show management that they're the same?

Is there a different way to demonstrate that the implementations are equivalent?

Comment: You don't need any of those continue statements: `if (!check1) error1(); else if (!check2) error2(); else if (!check3) error3(); else function();` works more succinctly and clearly.

Comment: Kernighan & Plauger in "The Elements of Programming Style" say something along the lines of "After you test a condition, do something" (meaning "don't test another condition").

Comment: I disagree that it is more clear without `continue`s. Its explicitly saying to go back to the top of the `while` loop, rather than scrolling all the way to the bottom to check that there isn't something outside of the else if...
I think that 'continue' is a useful tool that many are afraid of.

Sorry, my example code is short, the actual code cascades over 10 times and you cant see the bottom of the loop on a single screen. That's why I'm more inclined to use the `continues`

Comment: OK.  We're going to have to agree to disagree on the relative merits of `continue`, but what you're proposing is much better than what's there, especially if the nesting level is 10 deep for the conditions.  Proving that the two sections of code are equivalent automatically will be difficult.

Comment: my suggestion:  setup a test harness for the original code, have it test all conditions and combination of conditions, but do not orient it toward path coverage.   Then take that same test harness and run it again on the proposed code,  If the results are the same, then they are equivalent code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected that you will get different binaries.

Though it is simple to verify this change by just a code review, you can also run unit tests to validate the outcomes for all possible input conditions and prove that the outcomes match and also all the unit tests pass. This is if you can ensure complete code coverage by the unit tests.

Agree with Jonathan's comment about avoiding continue statements.

Answer (score 2):

As you only have three checks, there is only 2^3 = 8 different cases to check. And all you need to check is that the two solutions call the same function in each of the 8 cases.

So all you need to do, is to apply all 8 possibilities and print the name of the function called. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(void)  {printf("f  \n");}
void e1(void) {printf("e1 \n");}
void e2(void) {printf("e2 \n");}
void e3(void) {printf("e3 \n");}


void original_logic()
{
  int x = 7;
  int c1, c2, c3;
  printf("original_logic:\n");
  printf("c3 c2 c1 -> calls\n");
  while(x >= 0)
  {
    c1 = ((x & 0x1) == 0);
    c2 = ((x & 0x2) == 0);
    c3 = ((x & 0x4) == 0);
    x--;
    printf(" %d  %d  %d -> ", c3, c2, c1);

    // Logic from original code
    if (c1)
    {
      if (c2)
      {
        if (c3)
        {
          f();
        }
        else
        {
          e3();
        }
      }
      else
      {
        e2();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      e1();
    }
  }
}

void modified_logic()
{
  int x = 7;
  int c1, c2, c3;
  printf("modified_logic:\n");
  printf("c3 c2 c1 -> calls\n");
  while(x >= 0)
  {
    c1 = ((x & 0x1) == 0);
    c2 = ((x & 0x2) == 0);
    c3 = ((x & 0x4) == 0);
    x--;
    printf(" %d  %d  %d -> ", c3, c2, c1);

    // Logic from modified code
    if (!c1)
    {
      e1();
      continue;
    }
    if (!c2)
    {
      e2();
      continue;
    }
    if (!c3)
    {
      e3();
      continue;
    }
    f();
  }
}

int main() 
{
  original_logic();
  modified_logic();
  return 0;
}
```

which will output:

```
original_logic:
c3 c2 c1 -> calls
 0  0  0 -> e1
 0  0  1 -> e2
 0  1  0 -> e1
 0  1  1 -> e3
 1  0  0 -> e1
 1  0  1 -> e2
 1  1  0 -> e1
 1  1  1 -> f
modified_logic:
c3 c2 c1 -> calls
 0  0  0 -> e1
 0  0  1 -> e2
 0  1  0 -> e1
 0  1  1 -> e3
 1  0  0 -> e1
 1  0  1 -> e2
 1  1  0 -> e1
 1  1  1 -> f
```

Since the two tables are identical, you know the logic is identical.

Comment: This code given is just pseudocode to explain the situation, there are more, and they are not as straightforward as this appears.

Comment: @mr_guy99493 - well, even with 16 logical variables it's still possible within reasonable time to check all 2^16 combinations, pipe the output to files and do a file compare. If the structure of the code is different than the one shown... Hmm, it's pretty difficult to provide useful answer about code not shown :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative suggestion:

- It uses a single branch (`switch`) instead of several branches (`if`)
- It allows you to easily handle every possible combination of your `check` variables

---

```
while (x)
{
    #define COMBINATION(a,b,c) ((a? (1<<2):0)|(b? (1<<1):0)|(c? (1<<0):0))
    switch (COMBINATION(check1,check2,check3))
    {
        case COMBINATION(0,0,0): function(); break;
        case COMBINATION(0,0,1): error3();   break;
        case COMBINATION(0,1,0): error2();   break;
        case COMBINATION(0,1,1): error2();   break;
        case COMBINATION(1,0,0): error1();   break;
        case COMBINATION(1,0,1): error1();   break;
        case COMBINATION(1,1,0): error1();   break;
        case COMBINATION(1,1,1): error1();   break;
    }
}
```